# Deleting duplicate values occurring more than one time in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

Please tell me how to get the ImgFileNames whose HashCodes occur **more than one time** in Python. **Note: To retain only the first occurrence and delete the remaining even if the value occurs in-between or last or anywhere.**

I have a data frame like below :

```
ImgFileName         HashCodes
Img_0001 - Copy.tif 162a47470f021a60
Img_0001.tif        162a47470f021a60
Img_0002.tif        1b5b5b1aa638dac8
Img_0003.tif        adadadadadadadad
Img_0004.tif        adadadadadadadad
Img_0005 - Copy.tif a5b8648c8c666670
Img_0005.tif        a5b8648c8c666670
Img_0006.tif        71b392da6a699392
Img_0007.tif        71b392da6a699392
Img_0008.tif        b1b1f2fa6bf97292
Img_0009.tif        86e82ae4c8b6c9c9
Img_0010 - Copy.tif 86e8aae4c8b6c9c9
Img_0010.tif        86e8aae4c8b6c9c9
```

And I want the output as below:

```
ImgFileName         HashCodes
Img_0001 - Copy.tif 162a47470f021a60
Img_0003.tif        adadadadadadadad
Img_0005 - Copy.tif a5b8648c8c666670
Img_0006.tif        71b392da6a699392
Img_0009.tif        86e82ae4c8b6c9c9
```

Comment: Look at [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) - first filter all dupes and second filter last value of dupe or first value of dupe (`keep='last'`):

```
df =df[ df.duplicated('HashCodes', keep=False) & df.duplicated('HashCodes')]
print (df)
     ImgFileName         HashCodes
1   Img_0001.tif  162a47470f021a60
4   Img_0004.tif  adadadadadadadad
6   Img_0005.tif  a5b8648c8c666670
8   Img_0007.tif  71b392da6a699392
12  Img_0010.tif  86e8aae4c8b6c9c9
```

Or:

```
df =df[ df.duplicated('HashCodes', keep=False) & df.duplicated('HashCodes', keep='last')]
print (df)
           ImgFileName         HashCodes
0   Img_0001 -Copy.tif  162a47470f021a60
3         Img_0003.tif  adadadadadadadad
5   Img_0005 -Copy.tif  a5b8648c8c666670
7         Img_0006.tif  71b392da6a699392
11  Img_0010 -Copy.tif  86e8aae4c8b6c9c9
```